# express.js, MySQL pagination

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, express, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to paginate on the server but I am getting a syntax error from MySQL.

Sorry, I'm new, so I don't really understand where the catch is...

Here is my code:
(FullUrl its a concatination of BASE_URL and url - column from this table)

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  let numRows;
  let numPerPage = parseInt(req.query.npp, 10) || 40;
  let page = parseInt(req.query.page, 10) || 0;
  let numPages;
  let skip = page * numPerPage;

  let limit = skip + ',' + numPerPage;
    queryAsync(`SELECT count(*, concat('${BASE_URL}/', url) as FullUrl) FROM urls as numRows`)
     .then(function(results) {
      numRows = results[0].numRows;
      numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / numPerPage);
      console.log('number of pages:', numPages + 'number of rows:', numRows);
    })
   .then(() => queryAsync(`SELECT *, concat('${BASE_URL}/', url) as FullUrl FROM urls LIMIT ` + limit))
    .then(function(results) {
      const responsePayload = {
        name: 'marketing_campaign',
        data: results
      };
    if (page < numPages) {
      responsePayload.pagination = {
        current: page,
        perPage: numPerPage,
        previous: page > 0 ? page - 1 : null,
        next: page < numPages - 1 ? page + 1 : null,
        pages: numPages
      }
    }
    else responsePayload.pagination = {
      err: 'queried page ' + page + ' is >= to maximum page number ' + numPages
    }
    res.json(responsePayload);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.json({ err: err });
  });
});
```

MySQL error:

```
{
    "err": {
        "cause": {
            "code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR",
            "errno": 1064,
            "sqlMessage": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ', concat('http://localhost:3001/', url) as FullUrl) FROM urls as numRows' at line 1",
            "sqlState": "42000",
            "index": 0,
            "sql": "SELECT count(*, concat('http://localhost:3001/', url) as FullUrl) FROM urls as numRows"
        },
        "isOperational": true,
        "code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR",
        "errno": 1064,
        "sqlMessage": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ', concat('http://localhost:3001/', url) as FullUrl) FROM urls as numRows' at line 1",
        "sqlState": "42000",
        "index": 0,
        "sql": "SELECT count(*, concat('http://localhost:3001/', url) as FullUrl) FROM urls as numRows"
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a closing parenthesis in `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: your query doesn't make sense at all, count has no comma in it and the as can't also be in the count, so what do you want to count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can close the parenthesis.

But as you only want the count, why do you add another column at all?

```
queryAsync(`SELECT count(*) as numRows FROM urls as numRows`)
```

Comment: thank you, but... what a get - https://prnt.sc/19qenyq.  But what I need - https://prnt.sc/19qetjj

Comment: That makes more s nse as I already wrote use the changed answer